# jQuery on load get default checked value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have `input radio` list with custom `values` wich is loaded from the database. By default i have one item `checked` when window is loaded.

So when i try to grab that checked value i get `NULL`, but value of checked radio exist.

**Loop:**

```
<?php $first = true; ?>
<?php foreach ($prices as $item): ?>
   <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="price" value="<?= $item['price'];?>"  class="price"  <?= $first ? 'checked' : '' ?>> </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price" value=" <?= $item['price'];?>" class="price_field">&euro;</td>

    </tr>
<?php $first = false;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Whit this loop i get succesfull list of items and only first item is selected.

So now when page is loaded i want to get selected value and put him on other div like sum.

I try with jQuery but null

```
   $(window).on("load", function(){

        var price = $(".price");
        var total = $(".total");

        alert($(".price").val()); // null
     });
```

Comment: Try `var price = $('.price:checked').val();`. You need .val() to get the value in jQuery.

Comment: Why do you use jQuery when you can do it through PHP? Since you do it on page load anyways

Comment: @VincentDecaux u right this fix my problem. @Nordenheim i need jQuery bcs i have other ajax action when`change` event is triggered.

Comment: @Zend yes I understand, it makes sence, but in this particular reason jQuery seems like... I can't even call it an overkill or underkill. It's nonsensekill. PHP would have done a pretty good job inserting your variable into a div when generating a page, using jQuery for that seems like installing a second windshield on your car. Replacing the roof.